# Burninate [psychology]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Should we burninate [psychology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psychology) tag?

It has total of 56 questions asked, no tag wiki.

Tag description invites off-topic and opinionated questions. And for on topic questions that use libraries like [psychopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psychopy) it does not add any additional relevant information.

> Psychology is the scientific study of human affect, behavior, and
>   cognition. It is relevant to computer programming as it applies to the
>   design of computer programs that are written and user interfaces that
>   are designed in keeping with principles of how humans process
>   information.

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: This tag's meaning sounds more like it belongs to Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: @JRSofty more like [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Besides software for Psychological applications, Psychology is also important in designing UIs and Websites. I agree, that  questions about the psychological effects of xyz might attract opinion-based answers, but I don't think that justifies burnination.

Comment: @MikeMB IMO that is kind of my point. It is not suitable as tag because SO is for questions about specific programming problems and not psychological effects your design may have on your users. Those are probably suitable for User Experience as already noted. If you feel the need to tag your question with this tag it is most likely off-topic or uses some specific library where that library tag itself should suffice.

Comment: Most of them were very very old POB/TB questions. I closed the off topic ones (deleted the unsalvagable ones), and locked the famous ones.